# Best way to use Return Subroutine - Perl

Tags: perl

I have written a script which is working fine. But i am looking for better option if there is any:

Here is my logic: 
**From Test.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

    executeTest();

        sub executeTest {

        my $score = abc::executexyz($z,$x,$y);
        }
```

**From abc.pm**

```
    sub executexyz {

    #perform some operation
    my $check = getscore();
    return $check;
    }

    sub getscore {
    #perform some operation
    return $output;

    }

1;
```

Comment: What do you think should be "better" ...?  What bothers you with this?

Answer (score 1):

It is common and advisable to set up your packages so that they can export chosen functions. Then you add `use packageName qw(f1 f2);` to units that use the functions and they can say `f1()` and `f2()` without `abc::`.  When you do it this way one can then glance at the top of the script and see what packages are used, and what functions from them.  There are many other benefits.

File `abc.pm`

```
package abc;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp;

use Exporter;
our (@ISA, @EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK, %EXPORT_TAGS);
@ISA = ('Exporter');
@EXPORT_OK = qw(executexyz do_more);

sub executexyz {
    #perform some operation
    my $check = getscore()  or carp "Error: ";
    return $check;
}

sub getscore {
    #perform some operation
    return $output;
}

sub do_more { }

1;
```

There are other ways to do this.  Please search SO for packages, you will find a lot. Then scripts (or other packages) can `use` this package, importing only the functions they need.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use abc qw(executexyz);

executexyz();  # can use it without abc::
```

The line `@EXPORT_OK = qw(...)` makes listed functions available to other code for importing via `use`, so they can be then used without specifying `abc::` while other functions in the package cannot.  This is a preferred way of exporting symbols.

If you were to have a line like that for `@EXPORT` then all listed functions would be just pushed into the namespace of any unit that `use` this package.  This is almost never a good thing to do.

The `%EXPORT_TAGS` would allow you to set up groups of functions that can be imported by asking only for the tag name. I added it just to give you a hint that there is far, far more that you can do with package management.

This just barely starts the topic. See for example the  [package](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) page from perldoc, and for a lot more [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html). There are books and many tutorials out there. And mine SO.

Once you get packages down the next related thing would be to look up how classes are written.